# pgfgantt how do you connect start-start at the same time with three segment?

Tags: pgfgantt

In `pgfgantt`, connecting multiple simultaneously-starting bars by start-to-start produces a vertical arrow.  Does `pgfgantt` support a three-segment arrow, i.e. left, down, right? (finish-to-start seems to go five-segment in other tools, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just scrolling a bit in the manual, doesn't look like it's supported out of the box (unless I missed something). But you can define any type of link yourself with `\newganttlinktype`. Example below, more info in section 2.9 *Links* of the `pgfgantt` manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newganttlinktype{S-S}{
  \ganttsetstartanchor{west}
  \ganttsetendanchor{west}
  \draw [/pgfgantt/link] (\xLeft,\yUpper) -- ++(-\ganttvalueof{link bulge},0) |- (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{3}{6} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1b}{5}{6} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 2b}{6}{7} \\
  \ganttlink[link type=S-S]{elem0}{elem1}
  \ganttlink[link type=S-S, link bulge=1cm, link/.append style={red, dashed}]{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The manual's huge and I've been back and forth through it all day…haven't sat down and given it a thorough enough read yet, I guess.

Comment: @JohnMoser Actually, compared to some other manuals (notably, pgf/TikZ and `pgfplots`), the 50 pages of the `pgfgantt` manual isn't really all that huge ...  (Yes, the PDF is about 100 pages, but the last half is the documented code, so not something most people would need to read, I think.)